Calculating output impedance of amplifier to match to 50 Ω
Below is a schematic of an amplifier. The inductor used is a 1 μH inductor, emitter resistor is 2.2 kΩ. The bias resistors are both 200 kΩ. The capacitors are both 1 μF. I am planning to design a matching network to match it to a 50 Ω load and test it with a signal generator. How should the output impedance be calculated? I am planning to use this circuit as a buffer for a hartley oscillator.

Here is what I was thinking for calculating the equivalent output impedance (L is connected to ground):


Its connected to a 50 ohm antenna. Not a hw question.

Why does it need to be matched? Is there a long feed line to the antenna?

rf. output imepdance probably != 50 ohms. therefore, matching is needed.

No it isn't. Matching is needed to prevent reflections down feed-lines and sometimes we match for maximum power transfer.

rf. wavelength is small. small wavelength leads to reflection. therefore, matching is needed.

your circuit for calculating equivalent output impedance is incorrect. Also, impedance of one microhenry varies with frequency. There are some matching networks that are frequency-dependent...at what frequency should impedance matching occur?

L should go to ground in the equivalent circuit diagram. Output impedance is mainly defined by L. If you are looking for a 50 Ohm (pre)amp why not design it right away with 50 Ohm I/O impedance?

you're right. L should go to ground.

What I udnerstand is that you match it to the frequency you are working in. If the wavelength is smaller than the length of the traces, or the wire by a factor of 10, it needs to be treated like RF and requires matching for maximum power transfer. If a 100 MHz signal is going into this amplifier, match it to 100 MHz. If its 433 MHz, match it to 433 MHz, right? In this case, the inductor being a uH would factor also into the network right?

I thought the goal was to design a 50 Ohm amplifier. You didn't mention anything about a buffer-amp for an oscillator. The choice of a suitable buffer circuit depends on the oscillator.

So is the equivalent circuit for calculating output impedance correct as it is now? Can Itest and vtest be used to accurately calculate the output impedance or no?

@xcaliber99 - "the moderators prefer to restrict the scope of each post to a single problem" FYI it's not the mods. Restricting a post's scope to a single question is part of normal Stack Exchange etiquette e.g. this article, linked from the FAQ, explains that broad questions can be closed as "Needs focus". Then: "The question must be edited to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer, and not ask multiple distinct questions at once." SE still wants you to "give us details and context".

I see. I have not designed the oscillator yet but i want to use a hartley oscillator. I was thinking that the output of a hartley oscillator may need to be buffered. This circuit could act as a buffer as it has a high input impedance and the output couild be matched to 50 ohm. Is the equivalent circuit for calculating output impedance correct as it is now?

Your transistor model claims that the transistor output side is an ideal current source. The only output side impedance is inductor L. If you for some still unknown reason absolutely want that the output impedance of the amp with JUST EXACTLY THIS transistor  is 50 ohms, put a 50 ohm resistor in parallel with the inductor.
Use so high inductance that inductor's reactance is much higher than 50 ohms. Or insert a parallel capacitor with the inductor, select the capacitance so that together they are a resonant circuit at the operating frequency. The remaining output impedance is the inserted resistance in parallel with the resonant circuit.
I wouldn't waste RF power to the inserted resistor, but that's your way, selected by you when you decided the unreaalistic equivalent circuit of the transistor and started to want 50 ohm output impedance. I would worry how to make my load such that it doesn't reflect the signal back and how to make my amp to deliver what's expected to be got to the load. If the load reflects anyway, the amp should be made robust enough to tolerate the reflected wave. I would also worry how to either keep the amplification free of distortion or how to achieve a high energy efficiency and how the filter out the distortion frequencies. And all this with practical transistors.

Thank you for the suggestion. I will try this.

I added a capacitor in parallel with the inductor. The output was reduced by half. Why is this?

If you were running into a 50 Ω load then it might indicate that you've got a 2:1 potential divider and your source impedance is now 50 Ω - which is what you wanted!

@xcaliber99 maybe you only say "the amp should have output impedance =50 ohm" but actually you expect that the amp should work with 50 ohm load somehow well. You imagined that amp output impedance = 50 ohm implies  "working somehow well" which you couldn't describe. Now you got what you asked and wonder why the output voltage dropped 50%. Quite a typical result of making a classic XY-question (=asking something good looking, but obscure in terms of solving the actual problem)
